# Source code greyed out

Tags: html

I tried to download a video from some page, But the "view source" was greyout out and made it not available for downloading
here is the VLC, you guys can take a look. 
http://www.hbo.com/alzheimers/flash/VideoPlayer.swf?id=7&xmlPath=http://www.hbo.com/alzheimers/flash/xml/definition.xml

tried both firefox, chrome, not working 
tried "right click" + alt+command+U or G, not working either.

Can you suggest any other functional solutions? or it is about the link itself that hide the source?

Thanks!

Comment: use firefox->tools->page info->media and video file

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a flash video, use an swf downloader